# Flight Passanger details information in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Hello there i need help like while booking ticket that passenger details from appear on the page so if the user choose more than one traveller so how to implement on this pls help ....
Thank you

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: show us what you did, write your code and explain the section of code which has problem.

Comment: For Passanger details layout i didn't stated the code yet but i can Give you a reference like Install any flight Booking app (eg. Easy jet , indigo ) In Booking section try booking tickets (use date of 2021 to search flights bcz of this covid) while adding passanger try twice once select one Passanger and next time select more than one Passanger children anything than proceed on coming to the passage details form how that form appear like for one Passanger i can do that but more than one how do i implement that ....pls help